# How can I run this code from my terminal/prompt/shell

Tags: python, command-prompt

I am new to coding and would like to know how do I run a program on a terminal thing. I am following a video in which a person types out the name of the file he wants to run and it runs. What terminal/prompt/window do I need to type this in. I have a photo of the video tutorial and a photo of my desktop with all of my terminal applications. I keep getting errors, please help.

[Tutorial video showing the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSrJS.png)

[my terminal/prompt type applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0kUt.jpg)

Comment: Search "cmd.exe" in your start menu and whatever pops up there should be correct

Answer (score 0):

[image: python run in cmd]

Step 1: Create a python file in any directory of your choice

Step 2: edit python file and add some code (whatever you want to run)

Step 3: Open CMD by either clicking on Start and typing "cmd" or pressing and holding the "Start/Windows" button on your keyboard and pressing "R" on your keyboard, this will open a run window on the bottom left that looks like this
[image: run window]
In that "run" window type cmd. this will open a window that looks like this

[image]

Step 4: After opening CMD you will be able to type in it. type cd (Stands for change directory) and type or paste the directory of where the python file is located and press "Enter" Now you are in the directory of the python file see this for more detailed instructions on changing directories [Change Directories](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Directories-in-Command-Prompt)

Step 5: Type in the name of the python file, in this case, its "Hello World.py" and press "Enter" this will run the python file in cmd and show the result of the file in cmd

Good luck with your coding venture!